# Bind mount postgresql data on windows not work

Tags: postgresql, docker

If I use this bind mount for MySQL, it will populate the folder /mysql-data after container start

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:8.0
  volumes:
    - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

But if I use the same approach with PostgreSQL, the folder /pg-data remains empty

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:11.3-alpine
  volumes:
    - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql[/data]
```

I have tried both paths on the right side: `/var/lib/postgresql` and `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

I know I can use a data volume to persist postgresql data. But I am surprised, why the same approach works with MySQL but not with the PostgreSQL container.

Setup: Windows 10, Docker Desktop v2.0.0.3 (31259)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I detail check your issue, with `docker for windows`, `volumes: - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql` will mount windows folder `./mysql-data` to container's folder `/var/lib/mysql` with the ownership `root:root`. Then, `mysql:8.0`'s entrypoint will start the mysql server & put things in `/var/lib/mysql`, so you can see things in windows' folder.
2. But things different for `postgres:11.3-alpine`, if you check the log:

   ```
   PS E:\test> docker-compose logs postgres
   Attaching to test_postgres_1
   postgres_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
   postgres_1  | This user must also own the server process.
   postgres_1  |
   postgres_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
   postgres_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
   postgres_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
   postgres_1  |
   postgres_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
   postgres_1  |
   postgres_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
   postgres_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
   postgres_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 20
   postgres_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
   postgres_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
   postgres_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
   postgres_1  | 2019-07-09 13:50:21.843 UTC [47] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
   postgres_1  | 2019-07-09 13:50:21.843 UTC [47] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
   postgres_1  | child process exited with exit code 1
   postgres_1  | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
   postgres_1  | running bootstrap script ...
   ```

   You can see `data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership`, although the [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/ba24350aa02996f75cf5b44eea0af082775cc8ec/11/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L34) has did `chown -R postgres "$PGDATA"` to change the ownership from `root` to `postgres`, but unfortunately, this just works if you run the container on linux. For windows, this will fail, but `postgres` need this folder's ownership to be `postgres`, not `root`. So the service even did not start on windows, then, you certainly cannot see things pop up to your windows folder.
3. Finally, why `chown -R postgres "$PGDATA"` fail if docker host is windows?
   [This](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/39#issuecomment-285777521) is the answer.

   > Unfortunately, with the current implementation (based on CIFS/Samba) we can't improve this.
   >
   > Attempting to change these values via chmod/chown will return success but have no effect.
   >
   > https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html#id2532725
   >
   > I'm leaving this issue open for tracking.
4. What we can do?

   Currently, a workaround for this is to use named volumes:

   **docker-compose.yaml:**

   ```
   postgres:
   image: postgres:11.3-alpine
     volumes:
       - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   ```

   With above, the data will not be poped in to the windows folder `pg-data`, it will just maintained by docker itself. You can use next to check the volume:

   ```
   PS E:\test> docker volume inspect pg-data
   [
       {
           "CreatedAt": "2019-07-09T14:09:38Z",
           "Driver": "local",
           "Labels": null,
           "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/pg-data/_data",
           "Name": "pg-data",
           "Options": null,
           "Scope": "local"
       }
   ]
   ```

   Although the `Mountpoint` located in MOBY VM which is a Hyper-V machine you can not access, but it will always persist there. This means even you delete your container, next time, use the same named volume, your container still can use the persist data.
5. What can we expect?

   Maybe you can expect `WSL2`, which microsoft embed a linux kernel to windows, 
   then we can install docker in it, maybe could resolve this issue.

Comment: I understand. Now I am sure that the named volume is the only option in this case. Many thanks for the exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be permission issue. On the Docker host run.

```
chown -R 70:70 ./pg-data
```

If on Windows host, check if the folder has write permission to all the users (Everyone).

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I´m using Docker Desktop for Windows. Original post edited.

Comment: If on Windows host, check if the folder has write permission to all the users (Everyone).